# Как лучше сверстать этот заголовок?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

На десктопе расположить не проблема. А вот что бы при уменьшении экрана, он сначала вместе с картинкой сдвигался, а потом вообще на новую строку, не получается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тут js не причём - делается на обычном css3

Comment: А как именно делается?

Comment: Цифру с точкой позиционируется position: absolute, а на мобайл делаете  position: relative

Comment: Я же специально обвел красным кругом, то что мне нужно сделать. Цифру с точкой. Текст и картинку я и так могу расположить. А вот цифру с точкой расположить, а потом правильно адаптировать не получается.

Answer (score 3):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.block__item {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.block__img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.block__number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 700;
  z-index: 99;
}

.block__number>span {
  color: #f00;
}

.block--reverse {}

.block--reverse .block__item-content {
  order: 2;
}

.block--reverse .block__item-pict {
  order: 1;
}

.block--reverse .block__number {
  left: auto;
  right: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .block {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .block__item {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
  }
  .block__number,
  .block--reverse .block__number {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="block">
    <div class="block__number">01<span>.</span></div>
    <div class="block__item block__item-content">
      <p>На десктопе расположить не проблема. А вот что бы при уменьшении экрана, он сначала вместе с картинкой сдвигался, а потом вообще на новую строку, не получается.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block__item block__item-pict">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="block__img" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block block--reverse">
    <div class="block__number">02<span>.</span></div>
    <div class="block__item block__item-content">
      <p>На десктопе расположить не проблема. А вот что бы при уменьшении экрана, он сначала вместе с картинкой сдвигался, а потом вообще на новую строку, не получается.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block__item block__item-pict">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="block__img" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так [Туц](https://codepen.io/igachusko/pen/VdJBvY).

```
   <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-item">
  <div class="h2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex aut modi est voluptates beatae architecto numquam, exercitationem, voluptatem nulla ullam facilis, enim debitis quae fuga alias officiis dolores voluptate reiciendis.
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://dota.by/images/avatars//16882765904dd98d17c22fb.gif" width="100" height="100" alt="">
  </div>
    </div>
</div>

 .wrapper{
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:1rem 2rem;
  height: auto;
  display: table;
  outline:1px solid black;
}
.wrapper-item{
  position: relative;
  display: table-row;
}
.h2{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-right:1rem;
  width:350px;
}
.h2:after{
  content:'01.';
  color:blue;
  border:1px solid blue;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:.5rem 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  right:4.5rem;
}
.img{
   display: inline-block;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .h2{
    margin:0;
  }
  .h2:after{
    content:none;
  }
  .h2:before{
  content:'01.';
  color:blue;
  border:1px solid blue;
  transform:none;
  border-radius:50%;
  position: relative;
  display:table;
  padding:.5rem 1rem;
  bottom:0;
  margin:0 auto 1rem auto;
}
  .img{
    display:table;
    margin:1rem auto 0rem auto;
    text-align: middle;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

Размер экрана уже подбирайте сами и указывайте блокам как себя вести.

Но если поддержка старых версий браузеров не нужна- то тогда можно и на [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) сделать ну или вообще на [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) ( там вообще элементы можно как хочешь ставить и куда угодно).